# jquery-selective hide remove icon on a condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am facing the issue with plugin jquery-selective to hide the remove icon depending upon a condition inside the itemRemove() function.

> https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-selective

```
 itemRemove: function() {
       return <span class="${this.namespace}-remove">x</span>;
   },
```

Please help if anyone has any idea about this plugin.

Comment: where is your condition in the itemRemove function?

Comment: I want to put a condition on data but like other events listItem, item etc, this function don't have this parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by passing data it in below function from where this was being called, I did not notice that this function was being called from item function:

> item: function item(data) {
>                   return '\n
>   ' + this.options.tpl.itemRemove.call(this, **data**) + '\n
>   ';
>               },